# How to transform a cube into this

Tags: modeling, transforms

I've got a cube and I want to transform it into the object shown in this picture: 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it backwards:

[image]

- Create a circle
- Use Box Select to delete the lower half of the circle
- Select all of them and extrude upward
- Flatten the upper half with <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>RETURN</kbd> (might be another axis for you)
- (alternatively just extrude the side verts, select everything and fill the whole thing with <kbd>F</kbd>)
- Extrude the entire shape to give it depth.

### There's another way of doing this....

Take a cube and give it more resolution. Either with a Loop Cut or by subdividing the lower edges.

[image]

Then use the Proportial Editing Tool, set the falloff to spherical, select the middle edge and move the mouse up, restricting it to one axis. Doesn't always give a perfect circle though. More like an ellipse.

### Luckily there's another way of doing this...

Again use a cube that has enough resolution at the bottom, put a cylinder under it (use one with enough verts, 1024 segments are fine) and use a Cast Modifier on the Cube. Apply the modifier and get rid of the cylinder.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, but this is what came to mind:

Use the *Loop Cut and Slide* tool to split the cube vertically. Move the middle bottom edge up to the center of the cube (this would be exactly 1 unit in the Z axis if your using the default cube). Use the *Bevel* tool on the same selected edge to get the concave bottom (amount set to 2, segments to taste).

[image]

Comment: Another, maybe better way (nicer topology & all quads) would be to use multiple loop cuts, hide everything but the button faces and use proportional editing to move the bottom faces in the concave shape

Comment: I actually suggested that, too. Problem with that is that you don't get a truly spherical result unless you go full half circle. It gets kinda ellipsy

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the boolean modifier using a cilinder to help you out, select the cube, then the cilinder, open the modifiers tab, click boolean and follow the gif:
[image]

[image]

You have to select difference on the tab, and then hide the cilinder (select it and press H)